# Kinect v2.0 FaceFrameResult.FaceRotationQuaternion returning NAN

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

Using the kinect i am trying to obtain the yaw pitch and roll of a persons face. 
In order to calculate these values i am trying to obtain the FaceRotationQuaternion. However it seems to return NaN for the Y and Z values.

Example of rotation quaternion values:

```
X: 0 Y: NaN Z: NaN W: 2.80259692864963E-45
```

The code used for when a new face frame arrives.

```
    void FaceReader_FrameArrived(object sender, FaceFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var frame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (frame != null)
            {
                // 4) Get the face frame result
                FaceFrameResult result = frame.FaceFrameResult;

                if (result != null)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Found Face");

                    faceRotation = result.FaceRotationQuaternion;
                    double x = result.FaceRotationQuaternion.X;
                    double y = result.FaceRotationQuaternion.Y;
                    double z = result.FaceRotationQuaternion.Z;
                    double w = result.FaceRotationQuaternion.W;

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("X: " + x + " Y: " + y + " Z: " + z + " W: " + w);

                }
             }
         }
     }
```

The face is registered with the body.

```
  void BodyReader_FrameArrived(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
        {

            //Sent the data over bluetooth.
            //btc.sendKinectData(kinectData);

            using (var frame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
            {
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    bodies = new Body[frame.BodyFrameSource.BodyCount];
                    frame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(bodies);

                    Body body = bodies.Where(b => b.IsTracked).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (!faceFrameSource.IsTrackingIdValid)
                    {
                        if (body != null)
                        {
                            // 4) Assign a tracking ID to the face source
                            faceFrameSource.TrackingId = body.TrackingId;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How i can get the correct values using the FaceRotationQuaternion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It seems that the orientation of the head is also a feature and thus it needs to be loaded in before it works.

```
faceFrameSource = new FaceFrameSource(kinectSensor,0,FaceFrameFeatures.RotationOrientation);
```